# how to call newsletter subscription part in a specific page without XML in magento?

Tags: magento-1.7, php

I want to call the newsletter subscription part in a specific page.I don't want it in header.So I turned off it by disabling newsletter.xml page. To call compare product page generally we use

```
<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/product_compare')->getListUrl() ?>
```

Now by using php how can I call the newsletter subscription page?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the newsletter subscription url like this:

```
Mage::getUrl('newsletter/subscriber/new', array('_secure' => true)
```